# How to add a background using CSS in my Flask app.?

Tags: html, css, flask, background-image, flask-bootstrap

I am new to Flask and trying to add a background image to all of the pages of my web app. I have saved the background image as 'background-image.jpg' in an 'images' folder within a 'static' folder, in the project. Here is my 'base.html' file which is extended to all my other files.

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/custom-styles.css') }}">


{% block title %}
Flog
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
{{ ckeditor.load() }}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
    {% include '_navbar.html' %}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron background-img">
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for category, message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}    
    {% block sub_content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is my css file, saved in a 'css' folder within the 'static' folder named 'custom-styles.css'.

```
.background-img{
    background-image: url('..images/background-image.jpg');

}
```

When I run the app, the jumbotron is working but it just shows a grey box and no background image. Is anybody able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The url is wrong.  The `..images` type syntax is python specific.  Try `../images/background-image.jpg` or `/static/images/background-image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

```
.background-img{
background-image: url('../images/background-image.jpg');
}
```

Try adding the forward slash after the two periods, it looks like it might just be an issue with how the css file is accessing the images folder.

Answer (score 0):

The path to your background image needs to be correct. If that file is a static file then you need the static file path for the background image.

For example, if the path for background-image.jpg is:

```
path-to-static/images/background-image.jpg
```

Then instead of ..images/background-image.jpg you would need to use:

```
.background-img{
    background-image: url('/static/images/background-image.jpg');

}
```

That is, I believe, the default path to static files, though you can make configuration changes to that location.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this but still no luck, only the grey box! It is perhaps to do with the size of the background image and the size of the content block - should I be altering this?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console on a browser like Chrome to see if the resource is being loaded correctly? It's fundamentally a CSS issue despite being delivered by flask, so the questions are ones of syntax and whether or not the browser is correctly able to load the resource.

Comment: If the resource isn't being loaded, check to see if you can browse to it directly and what you see when you visit the image via URL.

Comment: One method to verify your path is correct is to use {{ url_for('static', filename='images/background-image.jpg') }} somewhere in the text of your template and see what path Flask generates for you. You can then use that path.